# Copy & Paste rows highlighted in blue but blank column F

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements

I am trying to select rows highlighted in blue and but has no value in column F. After that, copy those rows to new sheet. I tried highlighting selection first in green to check if it select those row but its not working. Thank you in advance.

```
Sub BLANKS()

    Dim LastRowS1 As Long, LastRowS2 As Long, i, n As Long
    Dim rng As Range

       LastRowS1 = Sheet10.Cells(Sheet10.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("F:F")
        
    With rng
        
        For i = LastRowS1 To 1 Step -1
            If Sheet10.Range("A" & i).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbBlue Then
             For n = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            
                If .Item(i) = "" Then
                
                .Item(i).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                   
            End If
            End if
           Next n
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Are the cells coloured by conditional formatting?

Comment: yes, i use conditional formatting but the excel is crashing because i have a lot of data.

Comment: What is `Sheet10` vs. `ActiveSheet` here?  Are they the same sheet?  Which is the sheet you're copying to ?

Comment: Is the code located in the workbook that contains the worksheet `Sheet10` (code name)? Does your code refer to one worksheet only? Is a row considered to be copied when the cell in its `A` column is blue and the cell in its `F` column is blank? If the condition (formula) that makes a cell blue is simple enough, you should consider using **it** in the code instead of using the color (share the conditional formatting formula). What is the code name of the other (destination) worksheet? Please do clarify by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68881861/edit) your post.